Configuring external style sheets to be used with lit element?
I'd like to provide a way for clients of a syntax highlighting web component to specify usage of an external syntax highlighting stylesheet.
For example this demo uses the render function to inline the default css from highlight.js.
  render() {
    if (this.language) {
      return html`
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@11.9.0/styles/default.min.css" />

    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <pre><code class="language-${this.language}">${unsafeHTML(
        this._code
      )}</code></pre>
    `;
    }
    return html`
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@highlightjs/cdn-assets@11.9.0/styles/default.min.css" />
      
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <pre><code>(${unsafeHTML(this._code)})</code></pre>
    `;
  }

And I suppose I could just define a data-theme attribute and the web component client can then configure the style sheet used for a theme as a string, and the render function could render it in like this.
${unsafeHTML(this.theme)}


I was wondering if there is a more "Standard" way of doing this with lit element?

standard HTML has the hidden attribute/ And with stylsheets you can set el.disabled = true / false   for first load you can do onload="this.disabled = true "
